# Azure Storage container command running extremely long

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am working with Azure Storage and having some issues when calling commands on a container. I am running it with a unit test and sometimes when a command is called on a container, it just sits and waits on that command for almost 5 mins. And if I wait long enough, it will continue and succeed. When running this, the container actually does exist so it's not having to create the container at all.

Has anyone else run into this problem? I tried setting a `ServerTimeout` on the `BlobRequestOptions` but it had no affect.

Here is a sample of what my code is doing:

```
var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
var options = new BlobRequestOptions() { ServerTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10) };
if (!container.Exists(options)) //<<<<this is where it hangs
{
    container.Create();
}
```

I have also tried it with `CreateIfNotExists()`:

```
var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
container.CreateIfNotExists(); //<<<this is where it hangs
```

It also hangs if I just try to list the blobs

```
var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
container.ListBlobs(); //<<<<this is where it hangs
```

It doesn't happen for every container but when it does happen for one, it seems to be the same one. I have checked and the container does exist.

Comment: Local or Cloud configuration ?

Comment: Cloud configuration. And I just found out that it is not with just those two commands, it's any command on a container. I've updated my question.

Comment: Have you used something like Fiddler or Netmon to see if the request is waiting on the storage service (ie. waiting for the HTTP call to return), or if the delay is in your app (ie. no free worker threads to handle the request)?

Answer (score 0):

I have reported a very similar situation: [Checking if item exists in Azure blob container takes forever (SDK 2.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681512/checking-if-item-exists-in-azure-blob-container-takes-forever-sdk-2-0). Haven't found an answer yet.

Answer (score -2):

Can you hook Fiddler into the setup and see if any meaningful information comes out of that? (see http://sepialabs.com/blog/2012/02/17/profiling-azure-storage-with-fiddler/ for setting this up)

If not, I'd suggest contacting support.