# Checking if item exists in Azure blob container takes forever (SDK 2.0)

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am in the process of upgrading my c# solution to use the new Azure SDK 2.0 libraries. I have made minor changes to account for the breaking changes in the 2.0 libraries but other than that, it 's the same code. I have tested against my local storage and everything seems to be working fine but when I test against production Azure blob storage, it takes an excessive amount of time just to check if a blob item exists. It literally takes a minute if not more to simply return a Boolean indicating if the item exists or not.

In the code sample below, the line that is taking a very long time to complete is "if (!blob.Exists())".

```
    public byte[] GetBlobContent(string blobName)
    {
        if (blobName == "") return null;

        var blobClient = _storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(_containerName);
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
        if (!blob.Exists())
        {
            return null;
        }

        byte[] buffer;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(ms);
            buffer = ms.ToArray();
        }

        return buffer;
    }
```

Are there additional changes that I need to make to my code to make it perform like it used to?

Comment: I tried your code just now and it seems to be working fine. First request always take a bit longer (may be a second or two) but never in minutes as you're observing. I would recommend running this code from your local computer and trace the requests through Fiddler so that you'll get an idea about what exactly is taking long time.

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue as well. Typically Exists() returns in a few milliseconds, but occasionally, it will take 2 minutes (give or take a few seconds). It's totally annoying!

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach would be to skip the Exists() check and just let DownloadToStream fail if the blob does not exist. You will need a try/catch block around DownloadToStream to handle the "expected" failure. This approach saves you a round trip to storage for every blob read, since it only has to make the remote call once instead of twice.

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddler** doesn't reveal anything. I experienced a similar issue where the process hung indefinitely, until the timeout kicked in. Try replacing calls to `CloudTable.CreateIfNotExists` with `CloudTable.CreateIfNotExistsAsync`, and calls to `CloudTable.Execute` with `CloudTable.ExecuteAsync`.

Unfortunately I can't tell you why this works. At time of writing, the `WindowsAzure.Storage-PremiumTable` **Nuget** package was in *pre-release* mode, and presumably buggy.